# jquery to count the number fo checkboxes in a row

Tags: jquery, count, checkbox

I have a table a shown below:

```
<table class="authors-list">
      <tr>
         <td style="font-size:10px;"><a class="deleteRow"> <img src="delete2.png" /></a></td>
         <td ><input type="text" id="product1" name="product1" class="rounded"/></td>
         <td ><input type="text" size='5' id="qty1" name="qty1" class="rounded"/></td> 
         <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h09_1" name="h09_1" class="rounded"/></td> 
         <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h12_1" name="h12_1" class="rounded"/></td> 
         <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h15_1" name="h15_1" class="rounded"/></td> 
         <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h18_1" name="h18_1" class="rounded"/></td> 
         <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h21_1" name="h21_1" class="rounded"/></td> 
         <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h24_1" name="h24_1" class="rounded"/></td> 
         <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h27_1" name="h27_1" class="rounded"/></td> 
         <td class="tdcheckbox"><input type="checkbox"  id="h30_1" name="h30_1" class="rounded"/></td> 
         <td><input type="hidden" name="checkedsizes_1" id="checkedsizes_1" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I want a  script, that when calls populates each rows `checksizes` field with the number of checked checkboxes in that row.

the fiddle can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/emL6x/8/

The jquery I have so far is:

```
countChecks(){
     $('.author-list tr').each(function(){
         var count = 0;
         var hdn = $(this).find('input[name^="checkedsizes"]');
         count = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length;
         hdn.val(count);
     });
}
```

This is not working at present. any help with the answer or fiddle is appreciated. I am using jquery 1.9.1.

keep in mind my table has multiple rows so needs to loop through each row.

Thanks again.

Comment: selector would be "input[type='checkbox']:checked". $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length will give you count

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, can you assist on the fiddle? appreciated.

Comment: `:checkbox:checked` is fine. It was typos, typos and more typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to declare something is a function and also to reference it correctly

`countChecks(){` must be declared `function countChecks(){`

and `countchecks();` is supposed to be  `countChecks();`

It's also useful, when you give a table a class `.authors-list` that you use the correct class name to select it

`$('.author-list tr')..` should read  `$('.authors-list tr')...`

http://jsfiddle.net/emL6x/11/

Everything else was perfectly fine.

Comment: It wasn't just typos, the inline function call required the functions to be declared in the correct scope (global)

Comment: I removed the onclick and replaced with jquery

Comment: Thanks popnoodles. appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You had some typos/ syntax errors, which I have amended:

```
function submitFunction(){
    alert("call countchecks");   
    countChecks();
    alert("checkedsizes populated");      
    alert("continue with submit");      
}

function countChecks(){
     $('.authors-list tr').each(function(){
         var count = 0;
         var hdn = $(this).find('input[name^="checkedsizes"]');
         count = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length;
         hdn.val(count);
         alert(count);
     });
}
```

You'll find your main error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: submitFunction is not defined` which you are getting because you are calling your function inline, so the function must be defined globally, which means you must not load the script onLoad. This can be done in jsFiddle and I have amended yours to create a working version: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emL6x/17/)

Comment: Thanks Billy, your input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pleasure to be an input :)

Answer (score 1):

You had lots of typos in your JS.  Here's code that works, without changing any of your markup except to remove the event listener from the button and putting it in the JS where it belongs:

```
$(function () {
    var countChecks = function () {
         $('.authors-list tr').each(function(){
             var count,
                 hdn = $(this).find('input[name^="checkedsizes"]');
             count = $(this).find('input:checked').length;
             hdn.val(count);
         });
    }
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function () {
        alert("call countchecks");   
        countChecks();
        alert("checkedsizes populated");      
        alert("continue with submit");      
    });
});
```

I've updated your fiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

here is the right JS code:

```
function submitFunction (){
alert("call countchecks");   
countChecks();
alert("checkedsizes populated");      
alert("continue with submit");      
}

function countChecks(){
 $('.author-list tr').each(function(){
     var count = 0;
     var hdn = $(this).find('input[name^="checkedsizes"]');
     count = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length;
     hdn.val(count);
 });
```

### }

other then the typos , you also need to change the Frameworks & Extensions setting on the left, default is 'onDomready', you need to change it to 'no wrap - in '.

Comment: Thanks. what does `no wrap - in` do? Thanks.

Comment: the inline function call required the functions to be declared in the correct scope (global), 'no wrap - in head' will declare those two function in the 'global' scope, not 'onDomcumentReady'. You declared those two functions in the 'onDomready' scope, you can only call them inside. Not outside from onclick event.